# angularjs show/hide elements based on rules in xml

Tags: angularjs

I considering options to show hide elements based on rules saved in XML object
I dont want to use ng-show="canShow()" since the function is called several times in angularjs scope lifecycle are there any other alternate options?

Creating a custom directive is an option but not sure if it is better

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd use xml but I'd convert it to a json/array and do something like `ng-show="data.foo.display"` with data defined in the scope:

```
$scope.data = MyService.xmlToJson(xmlData);
```

and the display property being either true or false.

Comment: display property is not that simple id calculated dynamically based on selections

Comment: Then refresh the data object whenever there is a select action? Maybe it's a filter that you want.